# Why this error come when useing npx create-react-app my-app?

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, npx

When I'm trying to install create-react-app, I'm getting this error

```
Copyright (C) 2015 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

PS C:\Users\George Bobby> npx create-react-app my-app
Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Users\George'
command not found: create-react-app
PS C:\Users\George Bobby>
```

Comment: seems at least one command in the toolchain has a problem with spaces in the path. Try creating a new directory `c:\reacttmp` and executing `npx create-react-app` there ...

Comment: I got ```Creating a new React app in C:\reacttmp\my-app.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...

npm ERR! cb() never called!

npm ERR! This is an error with npm itself. Please report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/cli/issues>

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\George Bobby\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-05-09T08_01_09_329Z-debug.log```
They aborted installation and deleted installed packages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated NPM and node
~ Thanks